# Algorithm to find pattern for user activity

Tags: algorithm, statistics, prediction, logistic-regression

I was trying to find algorithms that will find out patterns about user activity in a device say a computer or a mobile device, is their any specific algorithm for this?

As an example lets say the user does activity x at time y weekly, then to identify this pattern which algorithm I should be looking into.

Cheers.

Comment: This question is too general. What activity? Login/Logout? Printing? Browsing? `i = i + 1`?

Comment: Also the second paragraph gives an example of doing x about y times weekly. That's not much of "machine-learning" or "statistics" in here.

Comment: it could be any activity, as an example in a mobile device it could be switch on silent profile, disable wireless, adjust volume etc.

Comment: agrred it has nothing to do with machine learning, but statistics also include statistical learning which is required.